# Nginx rewrite path to query string

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

I use nginx (php-fpm) and fatfree framework. I need some redirect logic in my routing engine. It looks like:

```
http://example.net/page/...
```

Instead of dots there could be something like:

```
another.net/someurl
http://another.net/?local_query
another.net/path/to/article.html
```

It breaks nginx logic and I see 404 error.

My nginx config looks simply:

```
location / {
    try_files           $uri    $uri/    /index.php?$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include             /etc/nginx/conf.d/fastcgi_params.conf;

    fastcgi_param       SCRIPT_FILENAME     /var/www/$main_host/www$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param       DOCUMENT_ROOT       /var/www/$main_host/www;

    fastcgi_param       PHP_ADMIN_VALUE     upload_tmp_dir=/var/www/$main_host/tmp/upload;
    fastcgi_param       PHP_ADMIN_VALUE     session.save_path=/var/www/$main_host/tmp/sessions;
}
```

So when I use:

```
http://example.net/page/another.net/path/to/article.html
```

Nginx tries to find file in filesystem with name `article.html` as I understand. How to write rule to ignore any symbols when there is keyword `page` after domain?

Comment: use another `location` block, like `location ~ /page/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution #1:

Probably it doesn't work because there is no `fastcgi_pass` directive inside `/etc/nginx/conf.d/fastcgi_params.conf`.

If so, all you need is simply add it to your `\.php$` location. In general case it looks like:

```
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
```

but this line might be different, depending on how PHP-FPM is configured.

#### Solution #2:

Your current configuration makes Nginx pass request to PHP-FPM only if URI ends with `.php`.

To make Nginx do it when URI starts with `/page/` as well, you should write a new `location` with almost the same content (except for `SCRIPT_FILENAME` line) and (important!) put it before existing `\.php$` location.

Copying `location` content would cause a code duplication, and I would recommend write the config in a slightly different way:

```
fastcgi_param       SCRIPT_FILENAME     /var/www/$main_host/www$my_script_name;
fastcgi_param       DOCUMENT_ROOT       /var/www/$main_host/www;

fastcgi_param       PHP_ADMIN_VALUE     upload_tmp_dir=/var/www/$main_host/tmp/upload;
fastcgi_param       PHP_ADMIN_VALUE     session.save_path=/var/www/$main_host/tmp/sessions;
include             /etc/nginx/conf.d/fastcgi_params.conf;

location ~ /page/ {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    set $my_script_name /path/to/file.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    set $my_script_name $fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

In this case you will have 2 scenarios:

- if URI starts with `/page/`, Nginx will run `/var/www/$main_host/www/path/to/file.php`.
- if URI ends with `.php`, Nginx will run requested php file, as usual.

#### Solution #3:

Leave your `\.php$` location as is and put the following location **before** it:

```
location ~ ^/page/ {
    include             /etc/nginx/conf.d/fastcgi_params.conf;

    fastcgi_param       SCRIPT_FILENAME     /var/www/$main_host/www/path/to/file.php;
    fastcgi_param       DOCUMENT_ROOT       /var/www/$main_host/www;

    fastcgi_param       PHP_ADMIN_VALUE     upload_tmp_dir=/var/www/$main_host/tmp/upload;
    fastcgi_param       PHP_ADMIN_VALUE     session.save_path=/var/www/$main_host/tmp/sessions;
}
```

Just replace `/path/to/file.php` with real path to file which should handle such requests.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. When I put `fastcgi_pass` into any location I see an error:  `nginx: [emerg] "fastcgi_pass" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/conf.d/fastcgi_params.conf:
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed`

Comment: @Ockonal do you have other `location`s along with those two you posted in the question?

Comment: @Ockonal take a look at the Solution 3

Comment: thank you, it works in case of: `http://example.com/page/foo/bar` but fails when: `http://example.com/page/foo/bar.html` (404)

Comment: @Ockonal it looks like there is another `location` before that I posted, which intercepts `.html` request. If it is so, you may try put `^/page/` location before any other `location`

Comment: Amazing! I have caching location `location ~* ^.+\.(ico|htm|html|txt|jpg|png|gif|css|js)$` with html extension. When I put your example before this one everything started working. Thank you! :)

Comment: @Ockonal happy to help:)